# Bounded derivatives

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, derivatives

This is a result taken from an exercise in Bourbaki, Functions Of A Real Variable (pg 43, ex 12).

Suppose we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) which is $2$-times differentiable. Let $M_n=\underset{x\in I}{sup}\left | f^{n}(x) \right |, n=0,1,2$, then if $M_0$ and $M_2$ are finite, then so is $M_1$. Actually, $M_1\leqslant \sqrt{2M_0M_2}$. Moreover, if $f$ is defined on an interval a similar bound holds, provided that $length(I)$ is big enough.

The proof of this goes as follows: write $f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)/h+f''(\xi )h^2/2$, for some $\xi \in (x,x+h)$. Then $\left |f'(x)  \right |\leqslant 2M_o/h+M_2h/2$ and by minimizing the right hand side we obtain the result. But, this function of $h$ is defined for $|h|\leqslant|I|=length(I)$, so the minimum is attained, provided that $\sqrt{2M_0M_2}\leqslant|I|$. This does not bother us when $I=\mathbb{R}$.

Then it says that we can generalize. Suppose we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) which is $k$-times differentiable. Let $M_n=\underset{x\in I}{sup}\left | f^{n}(x) \right |, n=0,1,...,k$. If $M_0$ and $M_k$ are finite, then the rest of the $M_n$'s are finite. I cannot see a similar proof working, but let's believe the result momentarily.

I am wondering which of these results hold for holomorphic functions defined on an open set $\Omega$. If $\Omega$ is a union of lines (like a strip, or a half-plane) then i guess it holds, since if $g(t)=f(a+th)$, where $a\in \Omega$ and $h$ is a unit vector, then $g^{(n)}(0)=f^{(n)}(a)h^n$, thus $|g^{(n)}(0)|=|f^{(n)}(a)|$, so by using the previous result for $g$ and two of its derivatives $g^{(a)}$ and $g^{(b)}$, we can show that $f$'s derivatives of order $l$ such that $a\leqslant l\leqslant b$ are bounded. Is this thinking correct? Can the same be said if $\Omega$ contains segments instead of lines, whose lengths are big enough, like the exercise mentioned earlier?

Any help and/or insight would be great.